# Help identifying seal/gasket

Tags: seals

I need to identify the seal/gasket shown below so I can order a replacement. I can measure the OD, ID and Height, but I'm not sure what to call it to narrow down my search.

What type of seal is this? What are the parameters I should be searching for?

I don't need an exact match, but something close, as the use is very low-pressure.

It is used in a food-safe context with 100C water at near atmospheric pressure. There is no lubrication and is meant to be washed with food-safe detergents.

The seal has a flat side on the "bottom" that sits against a screw cap. The "top" side of the seal has two small lips that create the seal when the cap is screwed on. The inner diameter is flat and meets the bottom profile at a right angle.

The seal does **not** sit in a groove or channel in the cap, but just stretches around the OD of the threads and sits on a flat surface.

The seal has an OD of 63mm, an ID of 59mm and a height of 2mm. --These are my best attempt at measuring this as I am unsure how to properly measure a seal like this.

EDIT: Add OD, ID, Height

**Top side**
[image: Interface side - two lips]
**Lip Profile of Top Side**
[image: Profile of interface side]
**Bottom Side**
[image: Bottom side]
**Inner Diameter face**
[image: Inner Diameter]

Comment: https://www.henniggasket.com/food-grade-gaskets suggest writing them an email with the name of the device you pulled it from...I'm sure they know what it is.Looks an awful lot like a pressure cooker ring gasket however.

Comment: I have heard / seen that called a U seal - due to the section...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the tip - McMaster-Carr has an info section on u-cup seals. I think I might be on the right track, but these look a little too industrial: https://www.mcmaster.com/u-cup-seals -- What do you think? I

Comment: It looks somewhat similar to something on brewing equipment (except it is smaller).  Have you just tried searching by the equipment followed by the word gasket or seal?  For example "fermenter gasket"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a shaft seal or oil shield (which can be used for fluids besides oil, water/steam in your case).

Comment: I keep ending up on those when I look on McMaster-Carr. Wasn't sure if was barking up the wrong tree. This fits around a cap and then screws onto a cylinder with a thin edge.  The double lip appears to make a seal both inside and outside. Does that help at all?

Comment: Do you have a picture or schematic of the application?

Comment: Sadly, I do not. I only have the lid and the vacuum cylinder it screws into.